# Get the customer's total spend for a period of 1 year in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, orders

Using the code from [Show custom text based on total spent by user in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70245278/show-custom-text-based-on-total-spent-by-user-in-woocommerce):

```
add_shortcode('user_total_spent', 'get_user_total_spent');
function get_user_total_spent( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    ), $atts, 'user_total_spent' ) );

    if( $user_id > 0 ) {
        $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id ); // Get WC_Customer Object

        $total_spent = $customer->get_total_spent(); // Get total spent amount

        if( $total_spent > 600 && $total_spent < 1200 ){
            $text = __( 'congrats you are now tier 1', 'woocommerce' );
        }elseif( $total_spent > 1200 ){
            $text = __( 'congrats you are now tier 2', 'woocommerce' );
        }else{
            $text = __( 'congrats you are now tier 3', 'woocommerce' );
        }

        $total_spent = wc_price( $total_spent );

        return "Total Amount Spent: ".$total_spent." ".$text;
    }
}
```

This code receives the customer's total spend.

Is there a way to receive the total spend **only for the past year**, from customer “Completed” orders?

For example, if today is 2024/03/24, then the total spend should be taken only for the sum of “Completed” orders for the period from 2023/03/24 to 2024/03/24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following custom utility function to get the total spent from "completed" customer for a specific period (from the past year):

```php
// Utility function: Get customer orders total amount from specific status on a period
function get_orders_sum_amount_for( $user_id, $period = '1 year', $status = 'completed' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT SUM(total_amount)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_orders
        WHERE status = %s
        AND customer_id = %d
        AND date_created_gmt >= %s
    ", 'wc-'.$status, $user_id, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-'.$period) ) ) );
}
```

Then you can use it in the shortcode function like:

```php
add_shortcode('user_year_total_spent', 'get_user_year_total_spent');
function get_user_year_total_spent( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    ), $atts, 'user_year_total_spent' ) );

    if( ! $user_id ) return;

    $total_spent = get_orders_sum_amount_for( $user_id ); // Get total spent amount

    if( $total_spent >= 1200 ) {
        $text = __('Congrats you are now tier 3.', 'woocommerce');
    } elseif ( $total_spent >= 600 ) {
        $text = __('Congrats you are now tier 2.', 'woocommerce');
    } else {
        $text = __('Congrats you are now tier 1.', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return sprintf(__('Total Amount Spent: %s. %s', 'woocommerce'), wc_price($total_spent), $text);
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**SHORTCODE USAGE:**

- In WP post/page editor, or in some widgets: `[user_year_total_spent]`
- In PHP code: `echo do_shortcode('[user_year_total_spent]');`

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you tell me how to eliminate partial returns in this code? When the order is completed for 100 euros, but the user is returned 20 euros. The total spend still remains 100 euros, because...the status still remains "Completed".

Comment: The code doesn't handle partial refunds. You should ask a new question for that.