# Handle refunds in customer total spend for a defined period in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, orders

From [Get the customer's total spend for a period of 1 year in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215422/get-the-customers-total-spend-for-a-period-of-1-year-in-woocommerce/78216338#78216338) answer to my previous question:

```
// Utility function: Get customer orders total amount from specific status on a period
function get_orders_sum_amount_for( $user_id, $period = '1 year', $status = 'completed' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT SUM(total_amount)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_orders
        WHERE status = %s
        AND customer_id = %d
        AND date_created_gmt >= %s
    ", 'wc-'.$status, $user_id, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-'.$period) ) ) );
}
add_shortcode('user_year_total_spent', 'get_user_year_total_spent');
function get_user_year_total_spent( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    ), $atts, 'user_year_total_spent' ) );

    if( ! $user_id ) return;

    $total_spent = get_orders_sum_amount_for( $user_id ); // Get total spent amount

    if( $total_spent >= 1200 ) {
        $text = __('Congrats you are now tier 3.', 'woocommerce');
    } elseif ( $total_spent >= 600 ) {
        $text = __('Congrats you are now tier 2.', 'woocommerce');
    } else {
        $text = __('Congrats you are now tier 1.', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return sprintf(__('Total Amount Spent: %s. %s', 'woocommerce'), wc_price($total_spent), $text);
}

// SHORTCODE USAGE: [user_year_total_spent]
```

It receives the total spend for a certain period of time for all completed user orders.

But I was faced with the fact that if the order was partially returned, then the total spend is not reduced by the amount of the partial refund.

Example:
Order 3T-shirts * 10 EU.
Total spend 30 EU. Delivery costs are not included in the total spend.
Further, the buyer in this order returned 1 T-shirt * 10 EU. The administrator issued a partial refund manually.
Order status "Completed", 2 T-shirts * 20 EU. But the total spend is still 30 EU.

How to **exclude a partial manual refund** from the total spend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle WooCommerce refunds in customer total spent, replace the first function with:

```php
function get_orders_sum_amount_for( $user_id, $period = '1 year', $status = 'completed' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-'.$period) );
    $status = 'wc-'.$status;

    $total_orders = (float) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT SUM(total_amount) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_orders
        WHERE status = %s AND customer_id = %d AND date_created_gmt >= %s
    ", $status, $user_id, $date ) );

    $total_refunds = (float) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT SUM(r.total_amount)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wc_orders r
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}wc_orders o ON r.parent_order_id = o.id
        WHERE r.type = 'shop_order_refund' AND r.status = %s
        AND o.customer_id = %d AND o.date_created_gmt >= %s
    ", $status, $user_id, $date) );

    return $total_orders + $total_refunds;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.